# Geant 4, simulate Tc-99m decay

Tags: nuclear-physics, simulations

I have a setup of Monte Carlo simulations in Geant4, and I'm able to simulate radioactive events from isotopes such as I-131 and F-18, which are defined in the RadioactiveDecayData5.2 files.

Tc-99m is a metastable form of Tc-99, and is not directly defined in the isotope list.

Tc-99m is in the context of RadioactiveDecayData a daughter of Mo-99, but when used in nuclear medicine it appears as a single "isotope" with a internal transition (gamma emission) with an energy of 140.5 keV, half life 6 h, and a probability of 87% for the gamma to be emitted.

How can I define this gamma event? I can ignore conversion and Auger electrons for my purpose.

Comment: I don't know how many users here user geant4, so you may want to try asking this at the [geant4 forum](http://hypernews.slac.stanford.edu/HyperNews/geant4/cindex).

Comment: @KyleKanos you are probably right, I just wanted to give this a try.

Comment: I would suggest leaving this question here and if you get an answer there, perhaps you can take their answer and put it here (with proper attribution, of course). I think it would be useful to have such a question on the SE network.

Comment: Given its usage in real life, I’m actually surprised that there isn’t an entry for it somehow. Odd...

Comment: @JonCuster In my experience Geant users tend to be accelerator people, while Tc-99 is mostly used in medical contexts. There's not as much overlap between those communities as there should be.